# Deserialize json in java with static field

Tags: java, jackson

I have a class with a field which I would like to be static. Is there anyway I can use jackson to create an instance of this class? Right now jackson is ignoring the static field.

Here is an example.

Json:

```
{
 "index": "xyz"
}
```

JavaClass:

```
public class Foo {
  private static String index;
  ..
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Jackson issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-622) for this. And it is unresolved. And one of the programmers letf the comment:

> ... I haven't yet come across a real-world use for it.

Mixing this, I'd suggest you to find the way to change yor logic and make this variable non-static or extracting it to the other class.